# Angular / google map not drawing polyline between path points

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular-ui-router, google-polyline

Im very new to angular, the issue is my I unable to get agm-polyline to draw the path on my map. My data is populating my Array of objects but no action is being performed after that. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [fitBounds]="bounds" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="defaultZoom">
 <agm-polygon >
    <ng-container>
        <agm-polyline *ngFor="let polyline of polylines;let i = index;"  [strokeColor]="polyline.color" [visible]="true" [zIndex]="1">
           <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let pint of polylines.path" [latitude]="pint.lat" [longitude]="pint.lng">
           </agm-polyline-point>
       </agm-polyline>
    </ng-container>
    </agm-polygon>
   <sebm-google-map-directions [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [travelMode]="travelMode"></sebm-google-map-directions>
  </agm-map>
```

```
 this.polylines = this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,this.waypoints,this.firststopRec,this.laststopRec);


   private calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,waypoints,firststopRec,laststopRec){
    var waypnts = [];
    var pts = [];
    this.maxSpeed = 40;
 var getpnts = this.waypoints.map(function(item){
  pts.push({
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.latitude),parseFloat(item.longitude))
  });
  return pts ;
});
let pnts = pts;
console.log("pnts: "+ JSON.stringify(pnts));
var newPnts = [];
for (let pnts of pts) {
  newPnts.push(pnts.latlng);
}

   var frtLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(firststopRec.latitude),parseFloat(firststopRec.longitude));
   var lstLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(laststopRec.latitude),parseFloat(laststopRec.longitude));
    var request = {
      origin: frtLatlng,
      destination: lstLatlng,
      waypoints: waypnts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
   // console.log("request: {request}: "+ JSON.stringify(request));
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
      {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        //var route = response.routes[0];
        var routewypt = response.routes[0].legs;

        let polylines = [];
        let i = 0;
        let newPolyline = {path: [], color: 'red', strokeWeight: 3};

        for (let point of newPnts) {
          newPolyline.path.push(point);

            newPolyline.path.push( point[i+1] );
            polylines.push(newPolyline);
            newPolyline = {path: [], color: 'red', strokeWeight: 3};
          i++;
        }
        let pint = polylines;
        console.log('pint: ' + JSON.stringify(pint));
        console.log('polylines: ' + JSON.stringify(polylines));
       return polylines;

      }
    }); 
  }
```

My Data is there but the polyline path isnt drawing on the map

> [{"path":[{"lat":39.1876259,"lng":-96.58321000000001},null],"color":"red","strokeWeight":3},....]

Comment: you mean the data is not being reflected in view?

Comment: Correct and i cant see what is wrong

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: i think you are variable is local scope try to define the variable globally

Comment: The variables are  polyline: Array<any>;
  polylines:any;

Comment: can you add some more code

Comment: I've updated the Questions code section

Comment: did you try to force change detection manually?

Comment: I got the notification but the comment was gone when I tried to see it

Comment: this.ngZone.detectChanges(); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

Comment: Did you import changedetectorref

Comment: Yes I have imported it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is not being detected as it is happening outside of the angular framework within the asyncronous google directions callback. Make sure you include the change detector in the constructor, and only call change detection **after** the value has been assigned. Use a lambda to maintain the scope in the google directions callback.

**Force Change Detection**

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

...

this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, this.waypoints, this.firststopRec, this.laststopRec);


private calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints, firststopRec, laststopRec) {

    ...

    //USE LAMBDA HERE TO MAINTAIN SCOPE
    directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            ...

            this.polylines = polylines;
            this.ref.detectChanges();
        }
    });
}
...
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined. I have it imported and placed in the constructor

Comment: Can you share the full class including the constructor